# SQL is producing CROSS JOIN but I want INNER JOIN (records being multiplied)

Tags: sql-server, join

```
  SELECT *
  FROM        GRNHISTORY GR
  inner Join Inventorytransferlog itl on GR.ReferenceEntryID=itl.ReferenceEntryID
```

Both tables **GRNHISTORY** and **Inventorytransferlog** have their own ID column and unique ids. But we did not need it nor are we using it.
**ReferenceEntryID** is a `foreign key` from another table. Both tables have 10 records. Now when I run this query it shows me 100 records which I seem not to be able to understand. It should be showing 10 records as per my understanding. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM...?

Comment: It may help if you post `CREATE TABLE` statements including keys and `INSERT` statements with some sample data.

Comment: The 10 records have different / unique value on ReferenceEntryId ?  Important here are  the values for the ReferenceEntryId field, because you are joining by this field. See here an sample https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b38989829e78a373401194fc036b01c

Comment: As 10 * 10 = 100, I suspect your query is just producing a Cartesian product. Do all rows in both tables have the same value in `ReferenceEntryID`?

Comment: ditto SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is very unlikely to help, in this case.

Answer (score 6):

The answer becomes obvious when valid values are inserted for the `PRIMARY KEY`s of the two tables you are joining and you look at the results:

An example:

The two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE fred (int_1 INTEGER, ref1 INTEGER);   -- equivalent of GRNHISTORY
CREATE TABLE bill (int_2 INTEGER, ref2 INTEGER);   -- of Inventorytransferlog
```

The data:

```
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (1, 55), (2, 56), (3, 57);
INSERT INTO bill VALUES (21, 55), (22, 56), (23, 57); 
       -- NOTE: only 1 matching value of the JOINing refrerence field per table!
       -- and NOTE: different PRIMARY KEYs for the two tables!
```

The (your) SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM fred f
INNER JOIN bill b ON f.ref1 = b.ref2
```

The result (and [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f81e9f37c12c4d33be085776c0fc75b)):

```
int1 ref1 int2 ref2
   1   55   21   55
   2   56   22   56
   3   57   23   57
```

But, if the data is now changed as follows:

```
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (1, 55), (2, 55), (3, 55);
INSERT INTO bill VALUES (21, 55), (22, 55), (23, 55);  

       -- NOTE: 55 - ALL the values of JOINing reference columns in each record match!
```

Note that the joining field now has the same value in both tables for all records, then run the **same** SQL as above. Result (and [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de536932848e9164034919285fad84ae)):

```
  int1  ref1 int1 ref2
    1   55  21  55
    2   55  21  55
    3   55  21  55
    1   55  22  55
    2   55  22  55
    3   55  22  55
    1   55  23  55
    2   55  23  55
    3   55  23  55
```

And the result is a 9 (i.e. 3 x 3) records (effective) `CROSS JOIN` because your data makes it so! Because you've asked the SQL to `JOIN` on very common values in **BOTH** tables so therefore you can expect a lot of records in the result!

You can check this out by doing a

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ref1)) AS distinct_ref FROM fred;
```

answer = 1, (and the same result for bill with ref2).

I'm willing to bet that in your tables where you are getting a `CROSS JOIN` (or something very similar), that the SQL above using the `ReferenceEntryID` will get you very low counts (which also match in both tables) leading to many matching records in your `SELECT`.

There's the explanation for your apparent multiplication or `CROSS JOIN` - you have too many matching records in both tables - et voilà!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you are not using the unique `ID` you decided you don't need. Foreign keys are supposed to point to keys.

I suspect both tables have 10 rows with the same ReferenceEntryID.

```
SELECT *
FROM GRNHISTORY GR
Join Inventorytransferlog itl 
  on GR.ReferenceEntryID = itl.ReferenceEntryID
```

I suspect you need something like `GR.ID = itl.ReferenceEntryID`.

Comment: `Foreign keys are supposed to point to keys.` - maybe, maybe not. If you're joining through a joining table ([Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)), you mightn't be `JOIN`ing to a unique `PRIMARY KEY` - say if you're `JOIN`ing from a crew table to a crew_flight table to an airport table. Or from a student through a student_course table to a course_name field?

Comment: @Vérace Are you suspecting GRNHISTORY or Inventorytransferlog to be join table.  If there was a join table I would expect 3 tables.   Even on a join table it is pointing to a composite key.

Comment: True enough - I was just pointing out that your assertion that `Foreign keys are supposed to point to keys` is not universally true - although I will give you that if there are only two tables, that's what one would expect! However, one part of a composite key is not a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @Vérace Cool.  Did not want to confuse the OP.